# Search View in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Now I implements Search View. This search view search dream by name. But don't idea how to implements this function on Firebase.

// this is my reference to Firebase

```
   database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("dream");

    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<Dream> dreamList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot dreamCheckedSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Dream dreamChecked = dreamCheckedSnapshot.getValue(Dream.class);
                dreamList.add(dreamChecked);
            }
            dreamNotLoginAdapter.updateList(dreamList);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

//this method show search View method

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRy This**

```
  Query query = firebaseReference.orderByChild(CONSTANT.KEY_USER_NAME).startAt(stringQuery).limitToFirst(20);
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Popular mTrading = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Popular.class);
                        mTradingArrayList.add(mTrading);
                    }



                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    UTILS.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.alertUnexpectedError), getString(R.string.app_name), getString(R.string.ok));

                }

            });
```